# Responsive clock design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to make this clock responsive when i change screen resolution meaning put the clockwise in the middle of the clock and not moving during rotation

```css
.clock{ width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius:100%;
        margin: auto;
        background:#333 ;
        border:22px solid  rgb(41, 25, 25) ;
        position:relative;
        box-shadow:0 5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),inset 0 35px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 0 0 214px #c33;
}
.hour{
    position: absolute;
    top: 87px;
    left: 822.5px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 198px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0 0 #fff, inset 0px 198px 0 0 #333;
    transform: rotate(150deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
.minutes{
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    left: 822.5px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 170px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0 0 #fff, inset 0px 170px 0 0 #333;
    transform: rotate(150deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
             <div class="clock"></div> 
                <div class="hour" id="hour"></div>
                <div class="minutes" id="minute"></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: **Responsiveness** means getting rid of things like `px` in favor of responsive units like `vh, vw, %` etc. Thumbs up

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan in width and height or in the position

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.clock {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #333;
    border: 22px solid rgb(41, 25, 25);
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 35px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 0 0 214px #c33;
}
.hour {
    position: absolute;
    top: 87px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 198px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0 0 #fff, inset 0px 198px 0 0 #333;
    transform: rotate(150deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
.minutes {
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    left: 46%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 170px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0 0 #fff, inset 0px 170px 0 0 #333;
    transform: rotate(00deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
    <div class="hour" id="hour"></div>
    <div class="minutes" id="minute"></div>
</div>
```